# NHibernate many-to-many mapping to existing objects

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many

I'm having some issues with a many-to-many relationship I am trying to create.  The goal is to save a customer and which products they are allowed to purchase.  The products are not unique to a customer and will ALWAYS exist in the database before we try to associate a customer to them.

My mapping for the association currently looks like...

```
<set name="AllowedProducts" table="Customer_AllowedProducts">
      <key column="CustomerId"></key>
      <many-to-many class="Product" column="ProductId"/>
</set>
```

If I try to save a Customer I get a `NHibernate.TransientObjectException` referencing the product.  I understand that I could add cascade to the set, but I NEVER want to update or save a product when saving a customer, we only want to map a customer to existing products.

I should note that the customer I'm trying to save is coming in from a webservice call and therefore does not reference products that have been previously loaded into the session.  I would like to avoid have to load every product that will be mapped into the session.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
customer.AllowedProducts.Add(session.Load<Product>(productIdFromTheRequest));
```

Instead of what you are probably doing:

```
customer.AllowedProducts.Add(new Product {Id = productIdFromTheRequest});
```

It's worth noting that `Load` **never** goes to the DB; it just returns a proxy (or a retrieved instance, if one is present in the current session)

Comment: While I'm finding that Load is going to the DB (maybe something else I need to address, lazy does = true the Product mapping).  This totally solves the main issue.  Thanks

Comment: Lazy should almost NEVER be false; if it is, there's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to attach the product to hibernate session so that they become managed entity. As far as I know, there is no other way out.